# Measure the distance between two locations by road

Tags: android, distance, measure

How can I measure distance between two location by road in my Android application? I wrote code that measure the distance in a straight line, but I need code for shortest distance by road. What should I change in my code for it?

```
public double updateDistance(Location location) {
    float results[] = new float[3];
    Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(),
            location.getLongitude(), mLatitude, mLongitude, results);
    distance = results[0];
    return distance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the google maps api instead

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro?hl=en

you can see this too

[Google Map API v2 - Get Driving Distance from Current Location to Known Locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880778/google-map-api-v2-get-driving-distance-from-current-location-to-known-location)

Comment: Is there any solution that I don't have to change all of my code? My app works, but it measure straight line between my location and all locations from xml file.

Comment: To get the distance by road you will need the maps. I don't see any way around it. You can't calculate the driving distance without knowing where the streets are, and neither the location API nor the GPS coordinates have that information. Sorry I couldn't give you better news.

Comment: I've already had the maps. But on the MainActivity.class I measure distance from my location to locations from my xml file, but it measure the straight line. This is code:

Comment: private void updateLocation(Location location) {
  mCurrentLocation = location;
  for (Tour tour : tours) {
   double distance = tour.updateDistance(location);
   datasource.updateTourDistance(tour, distance);
  }
  refreshDisplay();
 }